# Can I perform a MySQL search using free text words?

Tags: mysql

How can I use free text search entries to find items in a MySQL table?

For example, I have a simple table of wines like below:

```
id  |  wine
================================
 1    Bollinger Special Cuvée Brut
 2    Bollinger R.D. Extra Brut 
 3    Bollinger La Grande Année  
 4    Bollinger La Grande Année Brut
```

I have earlier used the LIKE pattern method to be able to search for e.g. "La Grande" (`WHERE wine LIKE '%La Grande%'`), and it works fine for more exact search phrases.

But if the user provides a string such as "Bollinger Brut", or "Cuvee" (without the grave accent) then the LIKE pattern method won't find any matches. Can I solve this using some MySQL tricks, or do I need some other method/algorithm to be able to make more ad hoc searches?

Comment: Mysql has the option to do [Full text](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a FULLTEXT index like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `wine` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `wine` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `wine` (`wine`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

then:

```
select * from wine where match(wine) against('Bollinger Brut' in boolean mode);
```

will select:

```
+------+--------------------------------+
| id   | wine                           |
+------+--------------------------------+
|    1 | Bollinger Special Cuvée Brut   |
|    2 | Bollinger R.D. Extra Brut      |
|    4 | Bollinger La Grande Année Brut |
|    3 | Bollinger La Grande Année      |
+------+--------------------------------+
```

and:

```
mysql> select * from wine where match(wine) against('Cuvee' in boolean mode);
+------+------------------------------+
| id   | wine                         |
+------+------------------------------+
|    1 | Bollinger Special Cuvée Brut |
+------+------------------------------+
```

NOTE:

```
select 
   id, 
   wine, 
   ROUND(match(wine) against('Bollinger Brut' in boolean mode) ,5) score
from wine 
where match(wine) against('Bollinger Brut' in boolean mode);
```

will show:

```
+------+--------------------------------+---------+
| id   | wine                           | score   |
+------+--------------------------------+---------+
|    1 | Bollinger Special Cuvée Brut   | 0.01561 |
|    2 | Bollinger R.D. Extra Brut      | 0.01561 |
|    4 | Bollinger La Grande Année Brut | 0.01561 |
|    3 | Bollinger La Grande Année      | 0.00000 |
+------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

Because the  "Bollinger La Grande Année" does not have "Brut" score is lower. (But it is not 0 !)